# Bundle install in production on AWS fails with broken pipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, bundler

I'm deploying a rails application to a production server on AWS. When running 'bundle install' I am getting the error

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: IOError: Broken pipe (https://rubygems.org/gems/random.gem)
```

Every 'bundle install' installs one or two more gems, but ends up failing. I am using a m1.medium sized server. Do I need a larger instance or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had two problems. The first was that my bundler was outdated. I fixed that by running

```
gem update bundler
```

and the second problem was that I needed to bundle install as the root user since bundler was trying to install gems in a root owned location.

Hope this helps someone in the future.